# Using Platypus to create Mac OS X applications from a perl script

Tags: perl, platypus

Is it possible to get user input when using Platypus to build an application from a script?

I have a simple perl script. Which if I run from terminal, it asks for user input. But when I build an application file with Platypus, only the script's output is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is clear on this, no bi-directional communication; see http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#812

That leaves you with a few workarounds;

- [Use and expect script](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts) to inject your inputs;
- Update your script to take arguments, which is a feature supported by platypus;
- If you need to add more dynamic information, consider using a [TK dialog](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html) to query for user input;
- On mac you can use an osascript to call a dialog with minimum code;

**OSA Script Example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

sub osascript($) { system 'osascript', map { ('-e', $_) } split(/\n/, $_[0]); }

sub dialog {
  my ($text, $default) = @_;
  osascript(qq{
        tell app "System Events"
            text returned of (display dialog "$text" default answer "$default" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "$(basename $0)")
        end tell
  });
}

my $result = dialog("Life, the universe and everything?", "42");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful comment. I have installed TK modules for perl, and XQuartz on my Mac. This enabled my basic perl script to get user input using using a GUI interface, which was my attempt.